# Issue with responsive button add to cart (adjust width to page)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to adjust an add to cart button.

This is correct:

[image]

But when I change device then is still the same width;

[image]

I tried using:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

But something went wrong. Can anyone help me?

```css
.sparsh-buynow-view #product-sparsh-buynow-button {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  min-width: 500px;
  line-height: 2.2rem;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 5px 17px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="sparsh-buynow-view">
  <button type="submit" title="<?= /* @noEscape */ __($buttonTitle) ?>" 
  class="action primary" id="product-sparsh-buynow-button" 
  data-mage-init='{"Sparsh_BuyNow/js/buy-now": {"form": "#product_addtocart_form" }}'>
    <span><?= /* @noEscape */ __($buttonTitle) ?></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using mobile responsive or others???

Comment: @A.ANoman you can check on live https://feerdi.pl/calvin-klein-window-k2m23120-ladies-watch-k2m23120.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using vw instead of px for min-width.

```
.sparsh-buynow-view #product-sparsh-buynow-button {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  min-width: 50vw;
  line-height: 2.2rem;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 5px 17px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: this not solve our issue. You can check on live https://feerdi.pl/calvin-klein-window-k2m23120-ladies-watch-k2m23120.html